# How to condition if time reaches a certain second add one object

Tags: python, pygame

I am having a problem with regards to my condition if the seconds reaches 10 then add one more food object as shown below:

```
if int(counting_seconds) == 10:
    numFood += 1
```

But instead of adding only one, it keeps on incrementing the number of food, I may have found the problem which is there are milliseconds before the timer hits 11 but I couldn't figure out how to change my condition to only add 1. Here is my counting_seconds as well as milliseconds and minutes:

```
start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
counting_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() - start_time
counting_millisecond = str(math.floor(counting_time%1000)).zfill(3)
counting_seconds = str(math.floor(counting_time%60000/1000)).zfill(2)
counting_minutes = str(math.floor(counting_time/60000)).zfill(2)
```

Comment: You need to show us the full code, which shows how often you call the `if` statement. My guess is that this is in a tight loop which runs more than once a second, so it will increment `numFood` many times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to make sure that you only update once is to have a bool that you only reset when `counting_seconds` is not 10:

```
added_food = False

...

if int(counting_seconds) == 10 and not added_food:
    numFood += 1
    added_food = True
elif int(counting_seconds) != 10:
    added_food = False
```

Note: The `added_food` variable needs to be declared outside this scope so that it is not reset to `False` in every iteration.

Comment: Thank you so much! I never thought of having a bool to determine it you've been a great help!